# Genericity of local representation with a non-generic local A-parameter

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, p-adic-groups

Let $\pi$ be an irreducible smooth representation of a classical $p$-adic group. Suppose that $\pi$ has a local L-parameter associated to some non-generic local A-parameter $\psi$. Then I am wondering whether $\pi$ is non-generic representation. Does it differ from the characteristic of $\psi$?